# oracle queries with Lpad and Rpad

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to concatenate the blank values on left and right side of a string. I am using lpad and rpad command and concatenating them but I am unable concatenate the blank values to the left side. Example query below:

```
select lpad('',5,0)||rpad(city_name,20) from city;
```

output :Beaverton-11 blank spaces are concatenated.

can anyone suggest me the best solution for above query.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample values and what you want them to be.

Comment: Should the output be like `
'     Beaverton           '
'     London               '
'     Philadelphia        '`
? i.e 5 spaces before, and the city name padded to 20 chars?

Comment: The city_name doesn't have any defined size like it may be (london,america,england,italy) so,before evry city name i need to add 4 blank spaces. Later I need add some 5 blank space after the city_name .

Comment: It should be like  : eample 1 : ____italy_____  (_ should be considered as blank space just to make clear), example 2 :____america_____ .

Answer (score 1):

> I want to concatenate the blank values on left and right side of a
>   string.

*use this*:

```
 select lpad(' ',5)||rpad(city_name ,20) from city;
```

I see that you are trying to pad `'0'` s in your expression -  `lpad('',5,0)`.

If that is what you want, you could use

```
lpad(0,5,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation, oddly, does not state what the return value of LPAD is when the first argument is `null`. As you found out, the return is `null` in that case.

The third argument must be of some character data type. You are passing 0, which Oracle will big-brother-rly convert to the string '0'. But that's not what you want anyway.

The correct way to generate a string of five spaces is, as Kaushik Nayak showed in another answer already: `lpad(' ', 5)`. The default for the third argument is space, so you don't need to add it.

However, the simplest answer for your entire query is to lpad the result of rpad, like so:

```
 select lpad( rpad(city_name, 20) , 25 ) from ....
```

Now the city name is right-padded to length 20, and the result gets five spaces prepended (to make the length increase from 20 to 25).

To make it easier for future developers, you may even write `20 + 5` instead of 25 - to make it clear the intent was to add five more characters (which by default are spaces) to the left (**L**pad) of the result of RPAD.

Comment: Thanks for the response ..this method helped  to solve my query

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need to use 4 spaces before the city name and 5 spaces after the city name hence you can use the following ; use the following code

`select lpad(city_name, length(city_name)+4,' ')||rpad(' ', 4, ' ') from city;`